# Native URL Endpoints .plist for Ionic2/Swift stack

Tags: swift, cordova, ionic2

I work on a Ionic2/Cordova project and I am developing custom native plugins for accessing rest API's. As native, the language is Swift which is transpiled with Objc decorators to be able to match with Cordova.

For accessing this API's I need some strings with url endpoints. This is mocked right now by using a key value dict but I want to move everything into something accessible by every native plugin. One suggestion was to create a .plist file (URLList.plist) with the content of this dictionary

From what I understood, on a native project this would be in the resources and it would be called like this: `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "URLList", ofType: "plist").`

I don't know where should I add this plist in the Ionic project so that it will compile well so I can reference it in the Native code. I tried almost everywhere in the structure but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)
Adding then to the config.xml the required dictionary, on ionic build *platform* it will build and populate the plist.

After this, I used Swift to get the dictionary values.

I mainly solved the problem, though, I wanted to use a separate plist, not the main project plist.